Replace items of link by chrome extension
I have a problem with google extension.
When I click the button on my page the new tab is opened with this link.
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=6531234041&text=Hi+Agents%2C+I+am+interested+in%3A+%EF%BF%BD%EF...
I want replace "6531234041" and "Agents" as what I want. It depend on user's infomation.
For example https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=**6531234041**&text=Hi+**Agents**%2C+I+am+interested+in%3A+%EF%BF%BD%EF... to https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=**6590077500**&text=Hi+**MaxToh**%2C+I+am+interested+in%3A+%EF%BF%BD%EF... .
So if enable chrome extension this work should be done.
This is my basic code I tried.
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const whatsappButton = document.createElement('div');
    whatsappButton.className = 'whatsapp-button';
    whatsappButton.innerText = 'Contact Agent via WhatsApp';
    document.body.appendChild(whatsappButton);

    whatsappButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const agentPhoneNumber = '6590077500'; // Example phone number
        const agentName = 'Max Toh'; // Example agent name
        const currentUrl = window.location.href;
        const refID = new URL(currentUrl).searchParams.get('Ref ID');

        const newWhatsAppLink = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=${agentPhoneNumber}&text=Hi+${agentName}%2C+I+am+interested+in%3A+%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%;

        window.location.href = newWhatsAppLink;
    });
});

I tried with this code but the link is not changed.
I want know the way how to replace items that I want and move to link what I want by chrome extension.
Hope to your help.
